# How I can get a weblink in textview - Android

Tags: android, xml

I tired some codes but I couldn't fix it. My manu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_feedback"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

How I can get a weblink in this xml? Thanks a lot.

Comment: _I tired some codes..._ What exactly have you tried?

Comment: You want to start browser when menu item is clicked?

Comment: I'll put there a play store link. Web browser or Plah Store app doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example for a ContextMenu**

First override onCreateContextMenu:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(/*your menu id*/, menu);
}
```

Then override the onContextItemSelected an open a webview or the play store app:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case action_settings: {
                //your code
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```